# Can I add Custom frame to image in php

Tags: php

I have confusion regarding this. i have .psd file in which images are covered with attractive frames.
So. basically user uploads his/her photo. So how can i include that frame in user photo with php.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can use css for that

Comment: @Bindiya with background-image, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS instead

```
img{
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

border: width(px, %, em ...) type(solid, dashed ...) color(hex, rgb, rgba, named colors)

CSS3 now supports border-image

**better-example**

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as any example.

Comment: Ok, i'd just quickly found that. Really, this looks better: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/